# WCF to Flex : The best approach?

Tags: c#, wcf, apache-flex

I'm developing an ASP.NET web site with a n-tier backend utilising nHibernate - all good.  As part of the development a large portion of the Interface will be written in Flash or more specifically Flex 4.5.  In previous projects I would've created a webservice to broker data and actions between the Flash Interface and the business logic, however I'm looking for a more flexible solution that would allow data / objects to be easily passed to and from the service endpoint without too much redevelopment and with the onus of easy consumptionby Flex and others.

Enter WCF that seems to provide a robust server-side solution where we can use the existing POCOs in the business layer that can be easily serialised across the wire, amongst other things.  Unfortunately I'm unsure (and inexperienced in this field) at the best direction to enable the communication from my C# WCF webservice to my Flex application, there certainly seems a few directions but without a clear and concuse path to take.

I would also like the service to be able to communicate to other non-Flash clients so locking myself into one particular route is something I would like to avoid.  After some research I believe the best approach is for the WCF service to output lightweight data (i.e. JSON) or POX that should be easily consumed by Flex and other clients.  Unfortunately my prototyping has been rather frustrating where the only end to end route I've got working is to Import the Webservice into the application and setting the WCF service to use basicHttpBinding, something I believe I should be avoiding as we need to implement *somekind* of security and the desire to keep communication as lightweight as possible.  In addition, File Uploading would have to be factored in at some stage.

In short, what is the best method to have Flex communicating with WCF (and that's even if WCF is better than say ASMX) given the brief scenario above?  In addition, I would *really* appreciate any tutorials or links that would demostrate an end-to-end system.

Thanks in advance - S

Comment: OK - just to close off this thread...

Firstly Flex can only communicate with WCF using baseHttpBinding due to Flex not supporting later versions of SOAP.  Secondly, it is reasonably easy to create JSON endpoints with hardly any additional work and prototyping so far has been rather favourable.  Unfortunately my desire to use WCF for file uploads might have to be moved to a separate webservice.  Finally, my POCO required no contracts to be generated, they automatically serialized with no hassle.  HTH

Answer (score 1):

Flex has all problems and I wish flex and flash die soon if adobe is not keep up with today technology. I had a same problem to integrate ArcGIS-flex > WCF > CRM(Oracle). I found a solution with third party. This may help you if you decide to implement your solution using WebOrb

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Connecting_Flex_4_with_WCF_Services-17006.html

http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-net/developer-den/technical-articles/flex-net-integration.html#c1057